# All variables invisible to twig files

Tags: theming

I created a theme whose minimal.theme file contains the following lines (among others).

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for node templates.
 */
function minimal_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Declare the test variable and set its value.
  $variables['test_variable'] = 'Hello, this is a test variable!';
}
```

The following is the content of the template file.

```
{#
  This is a custom Twig template for the front page (homepage).
  It will override the default page template for the front page.
#}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Head content here -->
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Welcome to Our Website</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="my-custom-class">
      <p>{{ test_variable }}</p> {# not showing up #}
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

The template file does not show the value for `test_variable`?

What else do I need to do to make `test_variable` usable in the template file?

Comment: Preprocess node hook will make variables available in node templates. You are in the page template. Use preprocess page hook.

Answer (score 4):

Variables that are set in `hook_preprocess_node()` are only accessible in node templates. You are trying to access `test_variable` in a page template and that is the reason why that template file does not render any value for `test_variable`.

If you want to add the same variable to all the template files, you should implement `hook_preprocess()`.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess().
 */
function minimal_preprocess(&$variables, $hook, $info) {
  // Declare the test variable and set its value.
  $variables['test_variable'] = 'Hello, this is a test variable!';
}
```

You could also implement `hook_preprocess()` when the same code is used for more than one template file, but not all the template files. In that case, you can check the value of `$hook`.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess().
 */
function minimal_preprocess(&$variables, $hook, $info) {
  if ($hook == 'page' || $hook == 'node') {
    // The variable is accessible only from page and node templates.
    $variables['test_variable'] = 'Hello, this is a test variable!';
  }
}
```